# my jQuery script is not working with images, but working with all other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a jQuery script to drag elements over the document. I done the script and is working perfectly. but when I add an image the script fails. Why I cant drag an image over my document, I can drag other elements such as div, span etc . I am not interested to use jQuery UI for this purpose

my code follows

```
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  var x1 = y1 = 0;
  var drag = false;
  $(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#dv').mousedown(function(e){ 
      x1 = e.pageX - parseInt($('#dv').css('left'));
      y1 = e.pageY - parseInt($('#dv').css('top'));
      drag = true; 
    })
    $(document).mouseup(function(e){ drag = false; })
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){ 
      if(!drag) return
      $('#dv').css('left',eval(e.pageX - x1)+'px')
      $('#dv').css('top',eval(e.pageY - y1)+'px')
    })
  });
</script>
```

please check this [olario.com/jquery/first.php](http://olario.com/jquery/first.php) ( a normal div with text) working perfectly

second [olario.com/jquery/second.php](http://olario.com/jquery/second.php), that doesn't work with image

I spent two weeks to fix this issue, hope this forum will help me

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Strange, both examples work very well on Chrome.(although the img does not stop onmouseup)

Comment: I tried it in chrome as well and the only issue I had was with the browser trying to select the image as I dragged it.
Maybe you could make a div draggable and apply the image to it as a background?

Comment: As an aside, there are scripts like this out there, if you are looking for more functionality, e.g. [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).  I'm not advocating including another library for just this, but if it offers *other* features you're after, you may want to consider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it working with a tiny tweak in your mousedown event handler:

```
$('#dv').mousedown(function(e){ 

    e.preventDefault();

    x1 = e.pageX - parseInt($('#dv').css('left'));
    y1 = e.pageY - parseInt($('#dv').css('top'));
    drag = true; 

});
```

The [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) call stops the browser from trying to natively move the image itself and lets your script take over.

**Edit**

To get this working in IE, you'll also have to add a preventDefault() call to your mousemove event handler:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){ 
    if(!drag) return;

    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dv').css('left',eval(e.pageX - x1)+'px')
    $('#dv').css('top',eval(e.pageY - y1)+'px')
})
```

Comment: e.preventDefault(); doesn't work in IE, do you have a solution ?

Comment: Thank you pet, you have done a great job, Thank you very much, I was trying to get this for 2 weeks, Thanks again :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using classNames over ids.

Also after say 10 mousedowns on a target element, that element will have 20 listeners all firing when dragging since you never remove the listeners on mouseup.

Comment: This is incorrect, the mouse handlers are attached in `document.ready`, not in the `mousedown` handler, look closed at the code/parenthesis, I'll format to make it even clearer.

Comment: I stand corrected, my appologies ;)

Using id's instead of classnames for css expressions however limit the drag script to one single entity. Afaik, jQuery only returns the last found element with id X as per standard. Using classnames makes it more generic and predictable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>jQuery Drag and drop</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
#dv {
             position: absolute;
             cursor: move;
           }  
</style> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


<script language="javascript"> 
var x1 = y1 = 0;
var drag = false;
$(document).ready(function(e){

    //this is a possible solution
    jQuery('#dv>img').disableSelection();

    $('#dv').mousedown(function(e){ 

        x1 = e.pageX - parseInt($('#dv').css('left'));
        y1 = e.pageY - parseInt($('#dv').css('top'));
        drag = true; 

    })

    $(document).mouseup(function(e){ drag = false; })

    $(document).mousemove(function(e){ 

        if(!drag) return
        $('#dv').css('left',eval(e.pageX - x1)+'px')
        $('#dv').css('top',eval(e.pageY - y1)+'px')

    })
});
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 

<div id="dv" style="position:absolute;left:300px;top:200px;"> 
    <img src="http://olario.com/jquery/drupal.png" /> 
</div> 


</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```